# How to add validation on a phone number?

Tags: sql, oracle, check-constraints

How would I add validation on a phone number to be 11 numbers but start with the number 0 and allow +- etc? But still, be a bit flexible by allowing numbers. My lecturer told me to use an 'OR' statement but I'm not sure how to get it working

I have this currently but it doesn't allow '+-()' etc, I know how to use the 'OR' statement but I'm not sure how to attach it onto this:

```
CONSTRAINT  tutorPhonenumber1_ck 
CHECK (Phonenumber like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
```

Thank you all of your answers, VBoka's answer is basically perfect.

I realised i didn't put examples of what my aim was.

Acceptable phone numbers:

- 07123456789
- +447123456789
- 0121-258-3630
- 07436-123-322

These are the four criteria that I was looking for, well, this is what I could think for when a user would enter a phone number into my database.

Finally, the phone number should not accept letters- someone should not be able to type 'a' in the phone number.

Sorry for not clearing this up first :)

I'm using sql plus.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: I currently have this: CONSTRAINT  tutorPhonenumber1_ck CHECK (Phonenumber like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'), but if a person wants to typpe in +440745999999 etc it wouldnt work.

Comment: Can you give examples?  Where does the `+` come in if the number starts with a `0`?

Comment: Yeah sure, in the UK some people put in area codes in front of their phone numbers. This eliminates the first 0, thus the number (07458965555) would become (+447458965555) or if they wanted to it could become (07458-888-888)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I have put together:

```
check ( (length(phone) = 11 and
       phone like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]') 
       or
       (regexp_count(replace(phone,'+',''), '[0-9]') = 12 and
       phone like '+%' and
       regexp_like((reverse(phone)), '^[0-9]{12}'))
       or
       (regexp_count(replace(phone,'-',''), '[0-9]') = 11  and 
       (regexp_like((phone), '^[0-9]{4}') and
       regexp_like((reverse(phone)), '^[0-9]{4}')) or 
       (regexp_like((phone), '^[0-9]{5}') and
       regexp_like((reverse(phone)), '^[0-9]{3}')))
       )
```

By using `and` and `or` operators I have created 3 different conditions to be check:

- In first I check the length of the column `phone` and if it is 11 characters long then also check if every character of this 11 is numeric.
- Second condition checks if the string is 12 characters long but without the character `+`. If it is then check if it starts with `+` and check does it ends with 12 numbers.
- Third is first checking the length of the string without character `-` and then it checks does the string starts with 4 numbers and does it end with 3 numbers.

Comment: Hi, Yes i will, Just a quick question, is there any way of allowing a phone number like '0121-258-3630' to work?

Comment: I have updated the check with some more constraints... Cheers

Comment: In the final 2 conditions:  (regexp_count(replace(phone,'-',''), '[0-9]') = 11  and 
       (regexp_like((phone), '^[0-9]{4}') and
       regexp_like((reverse(phone)), '^[0-9]{4}')) or 
       (regexp_like((phone), '^[0-9]{5}') and
       regexp_like((reverse(phone)), '^[0-9]{3}')))
       ) ..is the first condion checking the it starts with 4 char and ends with 4 char and the second one if it starts with 5 char and ends with 3 char?

Comment: No, it checks if it starts and ends with numbers not char. But you are right about the second part of your question starts with 4 and ends with 4 or starts with 5 and ends with 3. Only it checks if they are numbers not chars I am covering this numbers with that: 0121-258-3630 AND
07436-123-322

Comment: Oh ok, but is the explanation that i provided of ".is the first condition checking that it starts with 4 numb and ends with 4 numb and the second condition if it starts with 5 numb and ends with 3 numb"

Comment: I have updated my previous comment with more details :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend regular expressions.  Something like this seems to match what you describe:

```
check (regexp_count(phone, '[0-9]') = 11 and
       regexp_like(phone, '^0[-+0-9]+$')
      )
```

Comment: This works but it does not allow users to enter in '+'. When i tried it it brings an error when someone uses the '+' as the number exceeds 11 characters.

Comment: This is the issue im facing that im not sure on how to make it relative. For example, allowing both 11 number phone numbers and allowing a phone number that has 13 characters (if they are using the '+' (the phone number would be +447458999999)). Or even having a phone number that allows the '-'.